# What is "sealing compound" for attaching a sink

Tags: sink

My directions simply say "Sealing compound", but an initial search on this isn't showing much.  What specifically should I use for attaching a sink top to the wood vanity it will sit on.

Comment: I suspect the answer is silicone caulk, but don't feel certain enough to consider it an answer.

Comment: Yeah silicone is the only thing I've ever seen used to seat a sink. Use actual silicone though, not latex caulk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several silicone or silicone-based adhesive caulks specifically forumulated for kitchen/bath use.  My personal favorite is DAP in the flexible tube.  But whatever trips your fancy...

Comment: Ended up using a 100% silicone adhesive.

Answer (score 0):

Some people use a strip of adhesive-backed foam to seal the edges of sinks. One example is this [Kinetic Assorted Size Sink Sealing Tape](https://www.bunnings.com.au/kinetic-assorted-size-sink-sealing-tape-4-pack_p4920416):

> Kinetic sink sealing tape is used for sealing underneath the sink for
>   both protection of bench top and eliminating leaks underneath the
>   bench top.
>
> This pack includes 2 rolls of 8 x 8mm x 2m and 2 rolls of 10 x 4mm x
>   2m sealing tape.
>
> - 8mm x 8mm x 2m - 2 Pack
> - 10mm x 4mm x 2m - 2 Pack
> - Flexible adhesive foam material

This stuff is quite good in that it's easy to install and lasts pretty well. However if it needs to be renewed, it can be a pain to clean it off the sink and counter-top.